# Link port from local machine to port in docker container

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that running kibana service on its `127.0.0.1:9200`. Now I want to connect from my local machine from port `9200` (`localhost:9200`) to that IP port in docker container. I tried but when I use curl to my local machine, I got  timeout error.
[image]

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's probably because your service is bound to '127.0.0.1'. Could you try `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`?

Comment: What is the output in verbose mode `curl --verbose 0.0.0.0:9200`?